# How to print out the letters(characters) from a user inputed string?

Tags: visual-c++

using an array, i cannot seem to figure out how to print each letter on a separate line from a user inputted string.

**Here is the code**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x, z;
    string fname, lname, name;
    char name_array[20];

    cout << "Please enter your name." << endl;
    getline(cin, name);
    x = name.length();

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        cout << name_array[i] << endl << endl;

    z = name.find(' ', 0);
    fname = name.substr(0, z);
    lname = name.substr(z + 1, x);

    cout << lname << ", " << fname << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `cout << name_array[i]` Make it `cout << name[i]`. You never initialize `name_array` - what data exactly do you expect it to contain?

Comment: I see now. the string variable "name" is an array of characters. Thank you